# Linear regression to compare proportions in different groups...?

Tags: arithmetic, regression

Days ago I asked this question ([Comparing proportions inside groups...?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842451/comparing-proportions-inside-groups)) and someone told me to compute a linear regression over each frequency distribution and compare the average residuals to see which one is the most directly linear relationship. Also, to compare proportions as I did, they told me to always take the arithmetic mean, not just when n >= 4.

However, I have some questions about this...

To do a linear regression, what would be "x" and "y" in this case?

Also, for the case of the group of 3 members how would I do the arithmetic mean? Wouldn't it be just 6/2 = 3? What would it mean to do the arithmetic mean when n<4?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scale of your problem, the type of analysis you would want to perform on a larger scale is called linear categorical regression. It's somewhat similar to log-linear regression for multiway categorical tables, but better because log-linear regression can blow up easily for large tables.  As an example, look at the SAS module called CATMOD, which is essentially based on what's called Grizzle-Starmer-Koch regression, which originated from UC Chapel Hill in the 80s.

You could run a module like SAS CATMOD without performing the steps/transformations you described, since it's not required.

Comment: How would this answer the original question about the *distribution* of wealth within each group??

Comment: CATMOD will perform within- and between-group tests for linear, sigmoidal and exponential (log) trends in proportions.

Comment: And how would that be related to the distributions in this question?  For background, it's worth reading the question the OP has linked to.